# File reading/writing proper order

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

So I'm working on this program that needs to create a file, writes into that file, and then read from that file. However, the file is not being written into but is still being created. First, Here are my declarations from the constructor in my file doing stuff class (called filer) :

```
private static FileWriter fw;
private static FileReader fr;
private static BufferedWriter bw;
private static BufferedReader br;
```

The main method of the main class first performs this openFile() method, which is in the filer class. Here is openFile():

```
public static void openFile() {
    try{ //exception handling
        file = new File("jibberish.txt");
        fw = new FileWriter(file); //dont put filewriter or buffedwriter before these, because already declared and end up
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  //making null expection thing
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    }catch(IOException ioe){ 
        System.out.println("Trouble reading from the file: " + ioe.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now in the main method, I set up a panel which all works properly from another connected class. There is a jTextField that takes what the user inputs, and runs it through this class, which is where I can not seem to be able to actually write in the file.

```
 public static void addStuff(String toAdd){ 
    String line = "";
    try {
        bw.write(toAdd);
        //bw.newLine();
        System.out.println(toAdd + " added");
        //line = br.readLine();
         while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line + "r");
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {               
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error at addstuff");
    }
}
```

So what I need the program to do, that it does not do now, is actually write into the file and be able to read it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should create both file reader and writer pointing at the same file at the same moment. You should first create the writer, write to the file, close the writer; then create the reader and read.

Comment: it worked for me, how is your main method?

Comment: you should create a singelton filewriter class, which will make writing and reading more controlled.

Comment: Try adding bw.flush() after bw.write(toAdd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you add

```
bw.flush();
```

to your code after the write to flush the buffer and get the data into the file to be able to read it back.

Comment: By adding this, it all works now. Thanks so much, but do you mind explaining why you have to flush the buffer?

Comment: Sure, the idea is that writing to disk takes a very long time, based on cpu cycles, so they buffer the write and let the disk write as fast as it can so that the program is not slowed down by the process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is really, because I just did what you just did and it worked for me:

here is the full class code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.model.geom.AddSubtractExpression;

public class a {

    private static FileWriter fw;
    private static FileReader fr;
    private static BufferedWriter bw;
    private static BufferedReader br;
    static File file;

    public static void openFile() {
        try{ //exception handling
            file = new File("jibberish.txt");
            fw = new FileWriter(file); //dont put filewriter or buffedwriter before these, because already declared and end up
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);  //making null expection thing
            fr = new FileReader(file);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        }catch(Exception ioe){ 
            System.out.println("Trouble reading from the file: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static void addStuff(String toAdd){ 
        String line = "";

        try {
            bw.write(toAdd);
            //bw.newLine();
            System.out.println(toAdd + " added");
            //line = br.readLine();
             while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line + "r");
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {               
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error at addstuff");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String... args){
        openFile();
        int i=0;
        while(true)
            addStuff("hello" + i++);
    }
}
```